# FFT for a single frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I was looking for a more efficient way of finding the magnitude and phase of a signal at a certain frequency without performing an FFT because it produces more information than I need and I came across this comment on the Matlab message board:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_original/250421.

If I am sampling at 1500Hz and my signal is 100 points and I am looking for the phase and magnitude at 15Hz, would this be suitable method for obtaining the information I need? Also, why does the OP suggest windowing the signal as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the Goertzel algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm
It is actually part of the matlab signal processing toolbox.